# How to fix this error message: Undefined variable: data

Tags: laravel

> ErrorException in 1e886a45102a3e4898f23b52cd7ca771 line 354: Undefined variable: data (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\soulfy_repo\framework\resources\views\soulfy\setting.blade.php)

Where should I put my code to define data?

**setting.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ action('HomeController@getBackgroundTheme')}}" method="post">
    <span class="setting-name">THEME</span>
    <!-- <form method="POST" action="/posts"> -->
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <span class="setting-value center">

        <select name="menu">
            <option value="Landscape">Landscape</option>
            <option value="Lifestyle">Lifestyle</option>
            <option value="Music">Music</option>
            <option value="Office">Office</option>
            <option value="Hobby">Hobby</option>
            <option value="Politic">Politic</option>
            <option value="Building">Building</option>
        </select>
        <!-- <div style="width: 150px; height: 30px;"><input type="image" src="http://localhost/framework_freshway/public_html/images/submit.png" value="SUBMIT" width="10"> -->
        <a href="{{ Url('home/users') }}">List User</a>

        @foreach($data as $d)

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img width="200px" height="200px" src="{{url('/')}}/uploads/{{$d->background}}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

        @endforeach

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </span>
    <br><br><br>

</form>
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function getBackgroundTheme()
{
    $data = user::all();

    return view('setting', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Comment: the `getBackgroundTheme` will be triggered after submiting the form !! for that you should also define you data in method that shows the `setting.blade.php` the first time !

Comment: Can you show the `Route`'s for this?

Comment: where to define data and how?  This is my route.php - Route::get('/home/theme', 'HomeController@getBackgroundTheme');

Answer (score 0):

- **To solve the problem:**
  check if `$data` defined before excute a loops

  ```
  @if (isset($data))
      @foreach($data as $d)

          <tr>
              <td>
                  <img width="200px" height="200px" src="{{url('/')}}/uploads/{{$d->background}}"/>
              </td>
          </tr>

      @endforeach
  @endif
  ```
- **Recommendation:** create form view and post form in two controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

You should either pass an empty array $data, or check if $data is set before using it. I personally prefer the second method.

```
@if(isset($data))
    @foreach($data as $d)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img width="200px" height="200px" src="{{url('/')}}/uploads/{{$d->background}}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getBackgroundTheme()
{
$data = user::all();

  return view('setting')->with('data',$data);
}
```

You are not passing variables to views. either you can `with` method or you can `compose`